# Any of four combinations are true? "Both X and Y are A or B" could be wrong?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

I want to write a sentence to mean that any of the following 4 situations are true.

1. *X* = *A* and *Y* = *A*,
2. *X* = *B* and *Y* = *B*,
3. *X* = *A* and *Y* = *B*,
4. *X* = *B* and *Y* = *A*.

The following sentence,

*Both are A or B.*

means only the first two cases in the list above. In other words,

*Both X and Y is A* **or** *both X and Y is B.*

So, I could write a sentence,

*X is A or B* **and** *Y is A or B.*

Am I right, or is there a better or concise way of writing a sentence for meaning that any of 4 situations are true?

Thank you for any answers.

P.S. Please, edit tags for this question if needed. I am not sure what tags are appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: I would say each of X and Y can be whether A or B.

Comment: *Whether* strikes me as strange. I would use *either* instead. But other than that I agree with Nate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nate might think that either A or B was a sentence. Because I considered A or B as words, _either_ is a correct choice. Thank you again.

Comment: Combining thoughtful answers from Pam, Nate, and RegDwighт, I could write a sentence 

_Each of A and B is either X or Y._

to mean that any of four combinations are true.

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, *X and Y can take any value A or B*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is better than joining two sentences.

Comment: Would you agree that _Both are A or B._ refers to only the first two cases in the list of 4 possibilities? I also want to know whether the sentence _Both are A or B._ is the same in meaning as the sentence you suggested.

Comment: I would agree. So, it should not the same meaning as my sentence. But wait for a native speaker confirmation too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would write

> X and Y can be either A or B.

For example:

> Dogs and cats can be either male or female.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like the simpler form without **Each of**. It seems ambiguous to me. When it is clear from the context, I would like to use your choice of the sentence, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

> *Both are either A or B.*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it ambiguous? The sentence, "_Both are either A or B._" seems to mean that only the first two cases of the four cases are true. I am not sure, though. I more like "**Each of X and Y**" than just **Both**. But, thank you for your thought.

Comment: I agree. The shortest form is *Each are either A or B*, or even *Each are A or B*.

Comment: Thank you!!! I like the simpler form with a slight modification: "_Each is either A or B._"

Comment: And I stand corrected. *Each* takes *is* not *are*.